# How can I use TLS RPC endpoint and tezos-admin-client at the same time?

Tags: node, rpc, tezos-admin-client

(Tezos version: `d272059bf474018d0c39f5a6e60634a95f0c44aa`)

I recently configured my tezos node with TLS certificate on the RPC API:

.tezos-node/config.json:

```
{
  [...]

  "rpc": {
    "listen-addr": "[::]:8732",
    "crt": "/home/tezos/my.website.crt",
    "key": "/home/tezos/my.website.key"
  }
}
```

Now, a command like `tezos-admin-client p2p stat` just hangs and eventually times out after several minutes.

If I remove the `crt` and `key` entries, the command works fine again.

How can I configure TLS and still have working local Tezos commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be to add `--tls` to the command like this:

`tezos-admin-client --tls p2p stat`